# Azure: Ingesting clickstream data from BigQuery

Tags: azure, google-bigquery, powerbi

I need to ingest event data from BigQuery into Azure, where the aim is to be able to apply some analytics on it.

So far I've been working with Data Factory. Now, the problem is, that I'm not sure how to transform and store the data. The data from BigQuery is heavily nested, an example of the structure:

```
   [
    {"event_date": "<int>",
     "event_timestamp": "<int>",
     "event_name": "<string>",
     "event_params": [
                 {"key": "<string>",
                     "value": {"string_value": "<string>",
                              "int_value": <int>,
                              "float_value": <float>,
                              "double_value": <double>}},
                 {"key": "<string>",
                     "value": {"string_value": "<string>",
                               "int_value": <int>,
                               "float_value": <float>,
                               "double_value": <double>}},
                {"key": "<string>",
                     "value": {"string_value": "<string>",
                               "int_value": <int>,
                               "float_value": <float>,
                               "double_value": <double>}},
                {"key": "<string>",
                     "value": {"string_value": "<string>",
                               "int_value": <int>,
                               "float_value": <float>,
                               "double_value": <double>}},
                {"key": "<string>",
                     "value": {"string_value": "<string>",
                               "int_value": <int>,
                               "float_value": <float>,
                               "double_value": <double>}},
                {"key": "<string>",
                     "value": {"string_value": "<string>",
                              "int_value": <int>,
                              "float_value": <float>,
                              "double_value": <double>}}
                    ],
     "event_previous_timestamp": <int>,
     + (more key-value pairs of user information etc)
     },
   { event2 },
   { event3 }, 
  ]
```

event2 and event3 means that there is a list of events each containing nested arrays described in the first part of the code snippet. I wanted to create a data lake type of solution with flat CSV files and Power BI reading data from there. I started with trying to flatten the data to CSV so it could be easily parsed by Power BI, but that caused the the data files to be multiplied in size. Power BI can take in JSON, but nested JSON is problematic as each of the nested array would need to be opened.

What do you think should be the approach here? All of the Microsoft/Azure ecosystem tools are available for me.

I can think of these options:

1. Stick with the huge flat CSV files, Power BI being really slow and the files taking a lot of space
2. Nested JSON in Power BI, use some power query code to automatically unnest data
3. Write data to an SQL Database where I could create connections between tables based on event ID

Do you guys have any ideas how to proceed? Let me know if my description didn't cover anything and I'll try to add to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that BigQuery is a data warehouse type solution and you are using it as a feed in to a data lake. Normally things go the other way, in to something like Big Query. PowerBI [has support for BigQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources) and a very capable direct / live query engine.

That said, I get what you are trying to do. We have faced all sorts of JSON nightmares, and like you, found that trying to unpivot and unbundle the JSON in PowerQuery is tedious and slow.

However, your JSON does not look that bad, if I read it correctly, I see it pivoting nicely in to CSV / TSV:

```
"event_date", "event_timestamp", "event_name", "key 1", "key 2", "key 3", "event_previous_timestamp", ...
```

From a pipelining perspective, I would land all the JSON from BigQuery in RAW format in to the lake, you can use [Parquet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-parquet) if you are concerned with volume. Then have a second activity transform the event JSON data in to simpler (flatter) JSON (maybe one structure for core event data and another for user data etc, linking all by EventId) and store it in a STAGED area of the lake for easier consumption in PowerBI.

Going one step further, you can add a SQL DB or Synapse as a DataMart to generate facts and dimensions if you want your PowerBI to be more performant and have the option of it working in DirectQuery mode.

We have strong developers on our team and use Azure functions to unpick crazy JSON files in to more sensible structures.

Not the greatest answer but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It definitely pushed me to the right direction. Your suggestion about pivoting the array elements into columns works well. In the original JSON data consists of multiple arrays, so I actually decided to unnest `event_params` into rows and the other arrays into columns.

Comment: However, it seems that the ADF's BigQuery API somehow messes up the queried data. Instead of the array nicely pivoting into columns in BigQuery SQL editor preview, in ADF the output is in one column as something like `{"v":{"f":[{"v":"user_properties_1_key"},{"v":{"f":{"v":null}, ....`

Comment: My SQL Query is:
WITH x AS (SELECT 
event_params AS arr_events, 
user_properties,
FROM events_table)
SELECT 
arr_events.key AS events_key, 
arr_events.value.string_value AS events_string_value, 
arr_events.value.int_value AS events_int_value,
arr_events.value.float_value AS events_float_value,
arr_events.value.double_value AS events_double_value,
user_properties[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] as user_properties_1,
FROM x, x.arr_events

Where `event_params` and `user_properties` are arrays, I want to unnest `event_params` into rows and `user_properties` into columns